# SetText EditText not working in Fragment using OnStart, OnResume and onCreateView

Tags: android

I am using Fragment and due to some reasons, EditText is not displaying the data retrieved from a POST request which gives JSON response.

There is no issue in JSON response. I also used OnResume and OnStart methods but still nothing working.

Am I missing anthing?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fragment_profile = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    InitializeControls(fragment_profile);
    NM_Profile.getInstance(this.getContext()).ViewProfile(new IResultListener<JOM_User>() {
        @Override
        public void getResult(JOM_User object) {
            user = object.getUser();
            if(user != null) {
                txtEmailAddress_Profile.setText(user.getEmailAddress());
            }
        }
    });

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
}


@Override
public void OnStart() {
    if(user != null) {
        txtEmailAddress_Profile.setText(user.getEmailAddress());
    }
    return super.OnStart();
}

@Override
public void OnResume() {
    if(user != null) {
        txtEmailAddress_Profile.setText(user.getEmailAddress());
    }
    return super.OnStart();
}
```

Comment: have you checked whether there is data in user.getEmailAddress()? or is it blank? are you sure that user is not null?

Comment: I can confirm that the data is present for the email address field. Kindly let me know if you need more details

Comment: have you tried to put a logcat instead of setText and check the value? although this might be a dumb question to ask but have you checked whether txtEmailAddress_Profile is defined such as txtEmailAddress_Profile = (EditText)findviewby id....?

Comment: Yes, txtEmailAddress_Profile  has the memory and already initialized. There is no problem in that.

Comment: This wrong way though. You dont make network request before building your UI. Dont do these stuff in onCreateView, just return the view there. And then in onViewCreated make request and fill editText. This might not be your problem but this is right way :)

Comment: Still you should add more info about debug, what is in object, can you log it, if you can there is something wrong with your EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Try initialising **txtEmailAddress_Profile** EditText inside the onCreateView() rather than InitializeControls().

Try something like this:

```
private EditText txtEmailAddress_Profile;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fragment_profile = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    InitializeControls(fragment_profile);
    txtEmailAddress_Profile =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.YourEditText);
    NM_Profile.getInstance(this.getContext()).ViewProfile(new IResultListener<JOM_User>() {
        @Override
        public void getResult(JOM_User object) {
            user = object.getUser();
            if(user != null) {
                txtEmailAddress_Profile.setText(user.getEmailAddress());
            }
        }
    });

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that the data is present for the email address field. Kindly let me know if you need more details